# Does Docker on MacOS support tmpfs?

Tags: docker, containers, docker-machine

I am new to Docker and I want to run Docker with ram only storage. In other words, I do not want Docker to save anything on persistent storage. I found out that on Linux Docker supports tmpfs. Is there any such support for MacOS? I have tried setting --tmpfs flag and docker run commands run fine on mac with that flag.

Comment: You might find this useful if you try to make Docker run read only. https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3872/how-do-i-make-read-only-mount-in-docker-container-writable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/#limitations-of-tmpfs-mounts) tmpfs is linux only.

**RAM disk**

If you want "RAM only storage", you can literally use a [RAM disk](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/how-to-create-a-4gbs-ram-disk-in-mac-os-x/). ie:

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'DockerDisk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://2097152 `
```

Then you can point volumes at `/Volumes/DockerDisk`. Drop and recreate at will.

Docker will still store its VM and images on disk. See: Docker > Preferences > Disk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you tell me about inmemory filesystem. It looks like it does exactly what I require. https://docs.docker.com/registry/storage-drivers/inmemory/ However I dont know how to configure it.

Comment: What I describe does not require the use of any special storage drivers from docker. MacOS is handling that for you. Just use it as a standard volume. eg: `-v /Volumes/DockerDisk/foo:/etc/foo`

Comment: okay sweet I have accepted your answer. Can you tell me how I can move the volume without using GUI on mac.. or should I ask it as a new question?

Comment: Might be better as its own question, just to keep the answers separate. Off hand, I'm not sure what you mean by "move the volume".

Comment: Here is my new question: https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4023/macos-how-to-move-disk-image-in-command-line

Comment: The "In-memory storage driver" referenced in the first comment is for registry specifically. It is not docker storage backend, but a docker registry storage backend, so irrelevant to the described problem.