# How to move disk image in the command line?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macos

As answered in this questions: [Does Docker on MacOS support `tmpfs`?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/4012/does-docker-on-macos-support-tmpfs/4020?noredirect=1#comment5811_4020) In order to run in memory docker, I need to move docker volumes to ramdisk. In macOS I can do it through docker preferences. However, I would like to write a script that could do it for me everytime I run docker on my machine. Is it possible to specify this setting using cmdline in mac?

Answer (score 2):

Docker is running in a VM on MacOS. One of your options is to put the entire VM on a tmpfs. You could use this shell script to create and mount the ramdisk: https://gist.github.com/koshigoe/822455

Here is a guide for resizing the machine. https://gist.github.com/stefanfoulis/5bd226b25fa0d4baedc4803fc002829e

The trick is to stop docker first, then you can make changes and move the

> ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2

wherever you like and symlink there from this location.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the question.

You tell docker where to put your volume data when you run the container. See [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems). It's not something you need to define in a global config. For example:

```
docker run -v /Volumes/DockerData/nginx_conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d nginx:latest
```

The above would run nginx but pull whatever config files you have in nginx_conf.

Comment: okay may be I am misunderstaing it. Isnt -v is only to mount some local host directory into docker? How I can specify to run docker in ramdisk.. that's my question. In other words how to specify nginx runs in ramdisk. I know how to do it using gui but I would like to do it in cmdline

Comment: You are correct. This is only for the container volumes, not the docker binary itself.